# C working with strings and SEGFAULT

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

Hello and sorry for my bad english.
I am starting with C language, but I didnt get pointers well...
I searched for similar topics, but I didnt get it from them, so I created own topic.
I have got main function, where I call function newSpeak.
There is my code of newSpeak, but there isnt everything...

```
char * newSpeak ( const char * text, const char * (*replace)[2] )
{
int i;
char * alpha;
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        alpha=strstr(text, replace[0][4]);
        if(alpha[0])
            strncpy (alpha,replace[1][0],10);   
    }
return 0;
```

}

Thanks for answering
EDIT: I have found source of the problem.
It works, when I dont use for cycle and run it once. But it doesnt work even when the condition in for cycle is i<1, which should make it run only once...This is strange for me...

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about what the `replace` variable is and what error you're getting (exactly)?

Comment: What is it supposed to do?  What is you intent here: `const char * (*replace)[2]`?

Comment: Hi @user3063800.  What is your question?  Are you asking why you are getting a SEGFAULT?

Comment: This looks like a problem: `const char * (*replace)[2]`

Comment: [Why are you using `strncpy()`?](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html)

Comment: Okay, replace variable is something like this: const char * chvariable [][2] = {
     { "first text", "second text" }}; And I am not getting errors.The program just falls down. I have to call that variable replace like this, so I cant change it... I use strncpy to copy it to alpha.

Comment: A pointer to an array of strings is defined like this: `char *str[2] = {"first text", "second text"};`

Comment: Its 2D array. Its, what my teacher set and he doesnt make mistakes in this...

Comment: Can I ask, what is the point of the `for` loop? You are not using the `i` in your loop, so you are doing some sort of replacement, followed by 3 potential replacements of the string with itself.

Comment: I guess replace the first four instances of the string...?

Comment: A couple more questions for you: your function is defined to return a `char*` but you are returning `0`. So what are you actually hoping to return here? If it's the modified function, then you need to return a pointer to a block of memory - and since `text` was passed in as a `const char*`, it would have to be memory that is allocated by the function but not freed. All pretty strange stuff...

Comment: I have extensively updated my answer - see if this is now enough to really solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
 strncpy (alpha,replace[1][0],10);
```

should have generated a compiler warning (and NEVER ignore compiler warnings). The function prototype is

```
char *strncpy( char *dest, char *source, int n);
```

But you are passing it `replace[1][0]` which is a character.  It might work if you passed

```
strncpy( alpha, &replace[1][0], 10);
```

Even then I still worry. It could be that since `alpha` is pointing to a block of memory in the block pointed to by `text` which is a `const char*`, that you are not allowed to modify that memory.

**EDIT** I think my first point is wrong - I misread your prototype. But I'm pretty sure the second point is valid (and probably the reason for the segfault).

**second edit**
It is possible that `text` does not have sufficient memory allocated to have 10 characters copied into it from `replace`. Realize that the thing you are matching against (`replace[0][4]`) and the thing you are copying (`replace[1][0]]`) are not the same thing; also, you are looping over `i` but not using that value ... makes me wonder if there is a typo (I am not clairvoyant and cannot figure out what you wanted to change from loop to loop).

You need to check the size of the thing you are copying into:

```
strncpy(alpha, replace[1][0], (strlen(alpha)<10)?strlen(alpha):10);
```

would ensure you are copying no more than 10 characters, and no more than there's space in alpha.

This is "on top of" everything else already pointed out (of which using `if (alpha!=NULL)` instead of `if(alpha[0])` is a big one.)

**EDIT 3** - I think I figured out the majority of the problems with your code now... see http://codepad.org/YK5VyGAn for a small "working" sample.

Issues with your code included:

1. You declare `text` as `const char*`, then proceed to modify it
2. You declare `replace` as `const char* (*replace)[2]`, then address element `replace[0][4]` (4 > 2...)
3. You assign the return value of `strstr` to `alpha`; this could be `NULL` (no match), yet you test for `alpha[0]` (which will fail if `alpha == NULL`).
4. When you copied the replacement string, you copied "up to 10 characters" - regardless of whether (a) the target string could accommodate this, and (b) the source string had this many characters. The result might be that you copy the full source string (including the terminating '\0') so that you will not find another match afterwards (you have "deleted" the rest of the string). And then you will run into the "strstr returns NULL" error...

Not sure (without seeing your input string or "replace" strings) which of these actually caused your code to fail - I have written a small program that addresses all of these mistakes. You can find it at http://codepad.org/4jSOnmPy - reproduced here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MIN(a,b) (a>b)?(b):(a)

char * newSpeak (const char *text, const char *(*replace)[5] ){
  int ii=0, n;
  char *alpha, *beta;
  printf("length of input string is %d\n", strlen(text));
  beta = malloc(strlen(text)+1);
  printf("allocated %d bytes\n", strlen(text)+1);
  fflush(stdout);
  strcpy(beta, text);
  printf("copy OK: beta now %s\n", beta);
  fflush(stdout);
  for(ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++) {
//    alpha=strstr(beta, replace[0][0]);
    alpha=strstr(beta, "a");
    printf("alpha is '%s'\n", alpha);
    fflush(stdout);
    if(alpha!=NULL) {
      char *rs;
      rs = replace[1][ii];
      printf("ii = %d; alpha now: '%s'\n", ii, alpha);
      fflush(stdout);
      n = MIN(strlen(alpha), strlen(rs));
      printf("n is now %d\n", n);
      fflush(stdout);
      printf("going to copy at most %d characters from '%s' into '%s'\n", n, rs, alpha);
      fflush(stdout);
      strncpy (alpha,rs,n);  
      printf("beta is now '%s'\n", beta);
      fflush(stdin); 
    }
    else printf("no match found\n");
  }
  return beta;
}

int main(void) {
  char* r[2][5]={{"a","b","c","d", "e"}, {"o","e","i","u","s"}};
  char* myText = "this is a vary sally strang";
  printf("NewSpeak: %s\n", "hello world");
  printf("converted: %s\n", newSpeak(myText, r));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
NewSpeak: hello world
length of input string is 27
allocated 28 bytes
copy OK: beta now this is a vary sally strang
alpha is 'a vary sally strang'
ii = 0; alpha now: 'a vary sally strang'
n is now 1
going to copy at most 1 characters from 'o' into 'a vary sally strang'
beta is now 'this is o vary sally strang'
alpha is 'ary sally strang'
ii = 1; alpha now: 'ary sally strang'
n is now 1
going to copy at most 1 characters from 'e' into 'ary sally strang'
beta is now 'this is o very sally strang'
alpha is 'ally strang'
ii = 2; alpha now: 'ally strang'
n is now 1
going to copy at most 1 characters from 'i' into 'ally strang'
beta is now 'this is o very silly strang'
alpha is 'ang'
ii = 3; alpha now: 'ang'
n is now 1
going to copy at most 1 characters from 'u' into 'ang'
beta is now 'this is o very silly strung'
converted: this is o very silly strung
```

Note - I added lots of "useless" output, including `fflush(stdout);` statements. This is a good way to ensure that debug printout shows you exactly how far into a program you got, and what was going on before it crashed - without the `fflush` it's possible you are missing many lines of output (because they never "made it to the screen").

It's obvious from the above that if your replacement strings are a different length than the string they replace, you will get some strange overwriting (I left both search and replace string length at 1 but there is no reason why that should be so).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I could be mistaken but I believe replace[i][j] _is_ a char* @Floris

Comment: I had no warning. Ahhh okay, I have now instead of text there: strcpy(beta, text); and alpha=strstr(beta, &replace[0][4]); and still it doesnt work :/

Comment: @codnodder - yeah; see my edit. I think your point is more likely to be right.

Comment: Okay, but that line isnt the problem. The problem is in line: alpha=strstr(beta, &replace[0][4]); I changed test for beta and copied test to beta by strcpy, bcs it was constant.

Answer (score 2):

```
    alpha=strstr(text, replace[0][4]);
    if(alpha[0])
        // looks crashy
```

man strstr:

> These functions return a pointer to the beginning of the substring, 
>   or NULL if the substring is not found.

EDIT:

It is difficult to tell what you are trying to do, but below find an arbitrary adaptation of your code. If it were my program, I would write it very differently. I mention that because I do not want someone to read this and think it is the way it should be done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void newSpeak (char *text, const char *replace[4][2])
{
  int i, j;
  char *alpha;
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (alpha = strstr(text, replace[i][0])) {
      for (j = 0; alpha[j] && replace[i][1][j]; j++)
        alpha[j] = replace[i][1][j];
    }
  }
}

int main ()
{
  char buf[100] = "abc";
  const char *replace[4][2] = {
    { "a", "e" },
    { "b", "f" },
    { "c", "g" },
    { "d", "h" },
  }; 
  newSpeak(buf, replace);
  puts(buf);
}
```

Comment: Good point. Probably want to check `if(alpha != NULL)` rather than `if(alpha[0])` - which will crash when there is no match.

Comment: You have a number of issues going on here. As Floris mentioned in his answer, you are copying over a `const char*`, which is masked by the fact that alpha is a `char*`.

Comment: So I have to have alpha const char* ?

Comment: That would stop masking your error from the compiler, but no, it is not the fix.

Comment: Okay and whats the fix?

Comment: Your function is trying to modify const char *test. You have to use a non-const buffer.

Comment: Ahhh okay, I have got now instead of text there: strcpy(beta, text); and alpha=strstr(beta, &replace[0][4]); and still it doesnt work :/

Comment: But it wont make sense for me this...I really need that function...Okay problem is weird now. If I comment for cycle, it works.It doesnt work even when  for(i=0;i<1;i++)
  {
  alpha=strstr(beta, &replace[i][0]);
  if(alpha != NULL)
   strncpy (alpha, &replace[i][1],strlen(&replace[i][1])); 
  }

Comment: You will have to edit your question and include more context, or a better explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay sir, everything works as long as I dont use that for cycle for it, so there should be problem.